# My parallax image isn't responsive for mobiles/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Upon the width of my screen being 682PX, my images width is not covered on the screen and it starts to disappear. It obviously isn't responsive and I am clueless why.

I have also included a class of 'img-responsive' to my section parrallax. That hasn't worked either.

```
<section class="module parallax parallax-1" class="img-responsive">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Services</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p></p>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
section.module:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module h2 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module.content {
  padding: 40px 0;
  height: 600px;
}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 600px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover !important; 
  margin-top: -30px;
}
section.module.parallax h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("../img/rolling.jpg");


}
```

Comment: I am not sure, is this what you are looking for? 
https://codepen.io/k185/pen/MmJXOv

Comment: Yes, exactly! The image is totally responsive. What did you change from my code? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Create an answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the section.module.parallax-1 part, I have added background features to this class. Also removed the section.module.parallax class as it has conflict with the result, which were asked in question

```css
section.module:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module h2 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module.content {
  padding: 40px 0;
  height: 600px;
}

section.module.parallax h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/dquSd5/rolling.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
  background-size: 100%;
top: 0;


}
```

```html
<section class="module parallax parallax-1 img-responsive">
  <div class="container">

    <h1>Services</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p></p>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, when I apply it to my code, my image still is not being responsive.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.

Comment: can you upload your image file somewhere

Comment: I think there is a problem in section.module.parallax with the background-size:cover !important;

Comment: I put your image in url and seems working fine to me, so if you resize the screen, the image would be cropped and resize according to it. if you want to keep the image as whole you should remove that background-size:cover !important;
but then your image will be resized in height and width

Comment: Is that image responsive in your browser? It isn't on mine and I am on Chrome. How unusual!

Comment: Your last image was.

Comment: Both hands aren't showing. As I shrink the browser it goes past the right hand!

Comment: @k185: would you be able to explain, _in the answer itself_, what was changed here? Future readers can be exhorted to check a particular section, but would you make it more explicit? Thanks.